# Sharing data between component using Angular service for Ajax Datatables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services, angular-components

I am new in Angular filed! So far I have liked but facing some difficulty in this following case. I want to send data from one component to another component once the user clicks a specific cell with **href** tag in the Datatables. Therefore I have created following .ts file

> service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

   private protDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
       currentprotData:null
   });
  currentprotData= this.protDataSource.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient

  ) {}

  sendProtData(currentprotData:any){
    console.log(currentprotData)
   this.protDataSource.next(currentprotData);
  }
get(url){
   return this.http.get(url)
      .pipe(
          map(responce=>responce),
         catchError(this.handleError)
    )

    }
}
```

> sender.ts

```
            import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
            import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
            import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
            import { HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
            import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
            import { MyService } from '../qmpkb/qmpkb.service';

            declare var jquery: any;



            @Component({
              selector: 'app-sender-page',
              templateUrl: './sender.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./sender.component.css'],
              providers:[MyService]
            })
            export class SenderComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
              dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
              dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
              private routeSub:any;
              errorStr:Boolean;


              @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
              datatableElement: DataTableDirective;

              constructor(
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private http: HttpClient,
                private renderer: Renderer,
                private router: Router,
                private _myserve:MyService
              ) { }

              ngOnInit(): void {
                    //let destPath='fileapi/resultFile/jsonData/resultJson/'+this.queryResPath
                    let destPath='assets/json/fake.json'
                    this.dtOptions = {
                        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
                        ajax: destPath,
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: false,
                        columns: [
                            { 
                                title: 'Prot Seq',
                                render: function (data: any, type: any, row: any, meta) {
                                    if (row["Prot Seq"].trim().length > 0 ){
                                        var array =(row["Prot Seq"].trim()).split('<br>');
                                        array.forEach(function(element, index) {
                                            array[index] ='<a target="_blank"   href="/seqfeatures" routerLinkActive="active" seq-link-id=' + element+'>'+element+'</a>';
                                        });
                                        return array.join("<br>");
                                    } else {
                                        return 'No';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    };



              }

              ngAfterViewInit(): void {
                this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {
                    if (event.target.hasAttribute("seq-link-id")) {
                          this._qmpkb.get(url).subscribe((response: any)=>{
                            this._myserve.sendProtData(response);
                          }, error=>{
                            this.errorStr = error;
                          })
                    }
                })

              }


              ngOnDestroy(){
                  this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
                  this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
              }
            }
```

> receiver.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyService } from '../qmpkb/qmpkb.service';
declare var require: any

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prot-view',
  templateUrl: './prot-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prot-view.component.css'],
  providers:[MyService]
})
export class ProtViewComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy  {
  message:string
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private _myserve:MyService,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
           this._myserve.currentprotData.subscribe(currentprotData=>{
           this.message=currentprotData
    })

  }




  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
          console.log(this.message)
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
  }
}
```

My service can recive data but reciver always retrun null. I am curius to know what is going wrong here! I really apprecite your help and advice!

**Updated**
 As DeborahK suggested to include part of project on stackblitz! You can check how I am trying to build this project!

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajaxdatatable)

Comment: What does `map(responce=>responce)` do?

Comment: @friddo I will receive some HTTP response data from backend in future, thought map may help to get JSON data! Just followed some example to do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems.Easy way is if you are subscribing to `sendProtData().subscribe` in `receiver.ts` that's wrong. You need to subscribe to `BehaviorSubject` and `sendProtData()` has **no return type** as well.

Make `protDataSource` as public and subscribe to it.

```
public protDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
   currentprotData:null
});
```

and then in **receiver.ts**:

```
ngOnInit() {
       this._myserve.protDataSource.subscribe(currentprotData=>{
       this.message=currentprotData
})
```

This so do the trick.

> UPDATE:

[Check this working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajaxdatatable-arckct?file=app%2Fsender%2Fsender.component.ts)

I fixed below things to make it work:

1. You should not inject service using `provider:[]` `@Component`. [It creates a new instance of service for each component.](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/dependency-injection-and-providers/ngmodule-providers-vs-component-providers-vs-component-viewproviders/#_component_providers) . You dont need that. You need both component to share same service instance to share the data. So, inject in `@NgModule` in `app.module.ts`
2. In the demo code, there was no `<app-receiver></app-receiver>`. I added that as well so as to initiate the component.

I hope it helped :) . Thanks for creating a demo

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have tried your solution but still at the receiver end,  getting following object=>currentprotData:null. Sender still gets that data! I am just wondering whether it is because of ngAfterViewInit() at sender.ts. Any advice to fix it!

Comment: @Paul85  can u confirm that `this._myserve.sendProtData(response);` is being called ? the null value is set while initializing the `BehaviorSubject` in `MyService` class. So, may be that value is retained and not the new one which you are expecting. Please check and let me know. You can also try setting some value at initialization of `BahviorSubject` and see if you are getting that in `receiver`

Comment: @Vivek I think `this._myserve.sendProtData(response)` is being called because If I do `console.log(currentprotData)` and  `console.log(this.protDataSource)` inside of `sendProtData` in `sevice.ts`, always getting the value which I send from `send.ts` but somehow its receiver is not receiving that data afterwards! Even I have initialized the `BahviorSubject` with some value and in this case, only getting that initialized value at the `receiver` end!

Comment: What is calling `sendProtData`?

Comment: @Paul85 : did u try subscribing directly to `public protDataSource` rather than `currentprotData` ?

Comment: @Paul85 It would be better if you can create a demo on stackblitz.com and share. What I suggested should have surely worked. I need to see a working demo

Comment: @Shashank  Please see the working demo of the part that project and you will find that receiver receive null-[AjaxDatatable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajaxdatatable)

Comment: @Shashank Thanks for the help! But still, I didn't get what I wanted to do. If I click the hyperlink in datatable from each cell, it will redirect to the new tab and then the "Hello new world" should be visible there means in the new tab! There is anyway Can I do it? Or angular has a limitation on this!

Comment: @Paul85 : This scenario isnt mentioned in your question. You were not getting the data which I fixed.  For opening in new Tab, your entire App will be loaded you will lose the data, One thing that you can do is pass routeParams when you redirect to new route in a new Tab. I hope you can mark it as answer for the question which you have asked. The comment section is getting longer and longer. In case you need more help feel free to create another question rather than changing the actual one. because it would invalidate all the answers which we are providing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your console.log:

**Instead of this:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
           this._myserve.sendProtData.subscribe(currentprotData=>{
           this.message=currentprotData
    })

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
          console.log(this.message)
  }
```

**Try this:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
           this._myserve.sendProtData.subscribe(currentprotData=>{
           this.message=currentprotData;
           console.log(this.message);
    })
  }
```

Comment: I have tried that too but still getting null. Even though I need to use that variable some point of time in ngAfterViewInit () at the receiver side! Anyway, I have edited my code because I realised that I can't use 'this._myserve.sendProtData.subscribe' at the receiver side but need to use this._myserve.currentprotData.subscribe(currentprotData=>{.

Comment: Just FYI ... Angular best practices is to normally use the `subscribe` in the component that needs the data.

Comment: thanks for the advice and normally I do but in this case always getting an error `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(currentprotData: any) => void'.` if I do `this._myserve.sendProtData.subscribe`

Comment: Any way to put a sample of the issue (*not* the entire application) into a stackblitz so we can take a look?

Comment: sure I will do soon

Comment: Please see the working demo of the part that project and you will find that receiver receive null-[AjaxDatatable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajaxdatatable)